# Blocked by Content Security Policy

Tags: iframe, blocked

I'm inserting from linkedin a embeded post code:

```
<iframe..... ></iframe>
```

but when is trying to load in my site I am getting this message:  Blocked by Content Security Policy
Please, could you advise how to avoid this message and load the frame in my site?. thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you didn't configure any particular CSP am I right? Is this site managed by cpanel or similar?

Comment: Hi, i did not do it, please advise how to do it?

Comment: You need to find out where is the CSP defined. It might be at a webserver level (as I said, if this is the case, you would do it through Cpanel) or at the code level. What kind of site is this?